# When i create a H2 Database its throws Error "DataBase Not Created"?

Tags: database, h2

When i create a H2 Database its throws Error "DataBase Not Created"

**Saved Setting :** Generic H2 (Server)
**Setting Name :** Generic H2 (Server)
**Driver Class :** org.h2.Driver
**JDBC URL :** jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test
**User Name :** sa
**Password :**

**Error :**
Database "C:/Users/rames/test" not found [90013-198] 90013/90013 (Help)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7p0Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Oh it will be good if someone answer here, because i have the same problem... Here is a picture below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

finally, I will solve my own System problem on the H2 Database.

**Solution :**

if your using the latest version of H2 DataBase, it does not work properly and it show error **"Database "C:/Users/rames/test" not found [90013-198] 90013/90013 (Help)".**

so, you should download the older version of H2 DataBase to fix the problem.

```
          **[ OR ]**
```

download older version and merge the file on already installed location

**follow the Steps :**

1. uninstall your latest version of H2 DataBase **[Version 1.4.199 (2019-03-13) or other version]
2. Go to H2 DataBase official site ( http://h2database.com/html/main.html )
3. click **All Downloads** option
4. click **Platform-Independent Zip**
5. click **h2-2014-01-18.zip**
   **link ::** 
   https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/h2database/h2-2014-01-18.zip
6. extract the **zip file**
7. click **h2-1.3.175.jar** on the Bin Folder.

now it's working *** enjoy ***